# In Excel calculate AVERAGE of an array result which in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have the below formula that Lookup the `A1:A10` appropriated Score Number.

```
{=INDEX(Table1[ScoreNum],MATCH(A1:A10,Table1[ScoreWord],0))}
```

I need calculate the AVERAGE result of this entire array.

But when using this:

```
{=AVERAGE(INDEX(Table1[ScoreNum],MATCH(A1:A10,Table1[ScoreWord],0)))}
```

Returns the first looked up result with Index/Match, against returns the average of all returnable values whit this array formula.

How can do that?

---

[The sample Workbook file](https://ufile.io/6zjnw)

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1 picture]

**Sheet2: Table1**

[image: Sheet2 picture]

**Note:** The formula in `B11` is: `=AVERAGE(B1:B10)` and returns the true value. I need return this without using the `B` helper column, directly in a single cell (`A11`) with the true form of formula shows in the picture.

Very truly yours.

Comment: What does the first formula return and where does it return the results?

Comment: It writed in `A14` and returns the first lookup value (The appropriated Score value of the `A3`)

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample of data. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To make the data useful edit your question to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: If assign the first formula to several vertical cells (same as `A14:A17`) it returns the several lookedup values.

Comment: Now use the range of the results to get the average.

Comment: @VBasic2008, How can I do that? Please write the right formula. thk.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I get update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Table1[Column2],N(IF({1},MATCH(A1:A10,Table1[Column1],0)))))
```

also entered as an array formula.

Comment: That is good, also. And there is a nice discussion of that method at EXCELXOR's website page  [INDEX:Returning an array of values](https://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/)

Answer (score 2):

I would use, instead, this **array-formula**:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(Table1[Column1],A1:A10,Table1[Column2]))
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

The `AVERAGEIF` function returns the array `{1;0.8;1;0.2;0.6;0.8;1;1;0.6;0.2}` which is what you are showing in your column `B` in your screenshot.

We then `AVERAGE` that array by nesting the `AVERAGEIF(..` within the `AVERAGE` function.